# Problems with luaotfload and certain font shapes

Tags: fonts, luatex, luaotfload

While playing around with `lualatex`on `TL 13` I encountered a strange problem. Certain font shapes would produce an error without any visible reason. The following example is with `Stempel Garamond LT Std` from Adobe's Font Folio 11, but I've encountered this with other fonts as well.

```
\documentclass[]{scrbook}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,ItalicFont={Stempel Garamond LT Std Italic},BoldFont={Stempel Garamond LT Std Bold},BoldItalicFont={Stempel Garamond LT Std Bold Italic}]{Stempel Garamond LT Std Roman} 
\begin{document}

Regular \textbf{bold}  \emph{italics \textbf{bold italics}}  

\end{document}
```

This leads to the following error message:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `EU2/StempelGaramondLTStdRoman(0)/m/sl' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `EU2/StempelGaramondLTStdRoman(0)/m/it' tried instead on input line 10.
luaotfload | load: auto-selecting default features for script: latn
luaotfload | load: no defaults for script “latn”, falling back to “dflt”
luaotfload | load: invalid request “/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/S/Stempel” of type anon
luaotfload | load: use square bracket syntax or consult the documentation.
luaotfload | load: path lookup of “/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/S/Stempel” unsuccessful, falling back to file: ! Font \EU2/StempelGaramondLTStdRoman(0)/m/it/10.95=/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/S/
Stempel not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
G
```

The really strange thing is that it produces the following output:
[image]
<sub>(source: [simifilm.ch](http://www.simifilm.ch/grafiken/luatexfontbug.png))</sub>

As you can see, `luaotfload` actually does find the correct font shape.

**EDIT**

It gets even weirder: I streamlined the directory structure. All fours shapes of Stempel Garamond Lt Std are now in `Users/simi/FontExplorerX/S/StempelGaramondLTStd/`. I let `luaotload-tool` update everything and `luaotfload-tool -F --find="Stempel Garamond LT Std Roman"` (or varieties of this) does give me the correct path.

When I try the MWE now, not even a PDF is produced. Instead I get the following errors:

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `EU2/StempelGaramondLTStdRoman(0)/m/sl' in size <10.95> not available
(Font)              Font shape `EU2/StempelGaramondLTStdRoman(0)/m/it' tried instead on input line 10.
luaotfload | load: auto-selecting default features for script: latn
luaotfload | load: no defaults for script “latn”, falling back to “dflt”
luaotfload | load: invalid request “/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/S/Stempel” of type anon
luaotfload | load: use square bracket syntax or consult the documentation.
luaotfload | load: path lookup of “/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/S/Stempel” unsuccessful, falling back to file:
! Font \EU2/StempelGaramondLTStdRoman(0)/m/it/10.95=/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/S/Stempel not loadable: metric data not found or bad.
<to be read again> 
G
l.10 \end{document}
                 
? 
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2013/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}

]
(./test.aux) )
```

As you can see, the path given here is not complete, which is strange since `luaotfload-tool` does know the correct path.

**EDIT 2:**

This is a confirmed bug which has been [resolved](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/95).

Comment: That means luaotfload gets passed a path ``/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/S/Stempel`` but cannot find a file of that name (is there?). Btw. funky characters like ``:()`` in your font paths won’t work. Wild guess, as I don’t have that font: does it help if you explicitly set ``SlantedFont=<...>`` (fill in your italic font name)?

Comment: It definitely is there like the other font files which are at the same location and are found. But as I wrote: `luaotfload` does somehow find the font file, otherwise it couldn't produce the shown result which is in italics. `SlantedFont` on the other hand results in a regular font being for `\emph{}`.

Comment: You really have a file (not directory) ``/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/S/Stempel``? The log says otherwise. What is the full path to the italic font?

Comment: @phg: See my additions to the original question.

Comment: If neither the path nor the filename contain spaces it should definitely work. After moving font files around you should clear the lookup cache: ``luaotfload-tool --flush-lookups``.

Comment: Spaces in filenames are not the problem here. The path to the font is `/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/S/StempelGaramondLTStd/StempelGaramondLTStd-Roman.otf` (-Bold, -Italic, -BoldItalic). No space whatsoever.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a bug in `luaotfload` and/or `luatex` with `\fontname`. It is triggered here because `fontspec` declares the italic font as a substitute for the (non-existent) slanted font. This will call latex's `\do@subst@correction`, which uses `\fontname\font` to load the substitute font. But with `luatex` (and `luaotfload`), `\fontname\font` wrongly returns the full path of the font (in your case `/Users/simi/FontExplorerX/S/Stempel Garamond LT Std Italic/StempelGaramondLTStdItalic.otf`) instead of its "name" (`"StempelGaramondLTStdItalic:mode=node;script=latn;language=DFLT;+tlig;+trep;" at 10.95pt`). This in turn will make `\font` explode.

You can prevent this from happening by specifying the slanted font explicitly, thus circumventing the substitution mess:

```
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
     ItalicFont={Stempel Garamond LT Std Italic},
     SlantedFont={Stempel Garamond LT Std Italic},
     BoldFont={Stempel Garamond LT Std Bold},
     BoldItalicFont={Stempel Garamond LT Std Bold Italic},
     BoldSlantedFont={Stempel Garamond LT Std Bold Italic}]
   {Stempel Garamond LT Std Roman}
```

Comment: Does indeed seems to do the trick (I also found out, that `luaotfload` is very fragile. I had to delete the font cache before this worked). I will report this bug to the `luaotfload` maintainers.

Comment: The problem is that ``\fontname`` reads from the ``filename`` field of the font data object. This field *must* contain the absolute path to the font file since if the font is outside the texmf tree, the font loader cannot find it for embedding even if the font metrics have been loaded correctly. Now, when ``\fontname`` is fed into ``\font``, spaces in the path will be interpreted as terminating the argument unless it is enclosed in double quotes. Imo the best solution would be having the substitution do a correct path lookup: ``\font\foo="[\fontname\bar]"`` or maybe read the file name in Lua.

Comment: @phg I don't know why `\fontname` has to read from the `filename` field (it didn't do that before, eg., with `luatex` 0.70), but in any case, `\fontname` should yield something that `\font` can digest. (And of course, latex2e will certainly not change, so your suggestion is rather futile in this case.) The problem is not only that spaces are being misinterpreted, but also that features will go missing: try `\font\x="Charis SIL:+tlig"\relax\fontname\x` (again, 0.70 did output the expected `Charis SIL:+tlig`, while 0.75 does not). BTW, `xetex` gets it right, too.

Comment: @Robert My remark about changing the call to ``\fontname`` wasn’t serious. Also, you are correct: it doesn’t read from ``filename`` but rather from the ``name`` field. I’ve set up the dev version in a way that this field is rewritten whenever the font is defined: see [here](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/95#issuecomment-18806110) if you want to test.

Comment: Is the bug fixed?

Comment: @Ingo Yes, see [here](https://github.com/lualatex/luaotfload/issues/95), as mentioned in the edit to the question.